# Workarounds for avoiding inconsistent line height with fractional pixels in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Situation: I want to display some text (or font icon) within a fixed height box. I can assume this will always fit on one line, so can simply use line-height to control the centering.

This works perfectly and shows two such boxes under each other:

```
<div class="box">a</div>
<div class="box">a</div>

.box {line-height:32px;width:32px;text-align:center;background:red;margin-bottom:5px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zj55racg/1/

Now, change the 5px vertical margin to 1.5px:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwg2ok3f/

In Chrome, I get the same nice-looking result. In Firefox however, the second box has the text visibly lower relative to the red box and does not look nicely centered at all.

Now while you would never use fractional pixel margins directly in the CSS, there is invariably text with a percentage line height, or responsive images, etc, throughout the page that results in fractional pixels being introduced. This means half the buttons throughout my page look nice; the other half look quite bad - the different is very noticeable.

Are there any ways the rendering can be worked around?

Image of what I see in case others can't replicate - the second a is a whole pixel lower in the red box than the first.

[image]

Comment: maybe update your firefox browser

Comment: .. it's up to date, as always.